# How to run two instances of Excel Add-In

Tags: excel, excel-addins, vba

How can I run two instances of Excel add-in?

The case is the following: I have an already implemented add-in. I duplicated the .xla file and I changed some of the code. After that I am  adding both add-ins to Excel. However when I call a function using the two different versions it always calls one method from the first add-in.

What is done wrong here? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: What part of the code will help you in order to understand the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Re:  Wrong macro run

When assigning the code to a button, menu item, ribbon thingy, use this syntax...

xxx.OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!SubOrFunctionName"

Note the single apostrophe (two places).

It would also help if you used a different names for the subs.